# lm.beta produces different results with standardized coefficients calculated by myself

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I was trying to use the following code to calculate the standardized coefficients:

```
rm(list=ls())
#install.packages("AER")
library(AER)
data("CASchools",package="AER")
CASchools$score=with(CASchools,(math+read)/2)
attach(CASchools)
#regular regressopm
lm1<-lm(score~income)
#standardized regression
stdscore<-(score-mean(score)/sd(score))
stdincome<-(income-mean(income))/sd(income)
lm1e<-lm(stdscore~stdincome)

#standardized regression provided by different package
#install.packages("QuantPsyc")
library(QuantPsyc)
lm.beta(lm1)

#but lm.beta is different from the coefficients I calculated with standardized regression
lm1e$coef
```

However, it seems that the output from the QuantPsyc package is different from the results obtained by myself standardizing the regressors and dependant variables.

The two outputs are:

```
> lm.beta(lm1)
   income 
0.7124308 

> lm1e$coef
(Intercept)   stdincome 
  619.82365    13.57419
```

As you can see, one of the results is 0.7124308, another one is 13.57419.They should be equivalent from my understanding.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made an error in how you scaled your variables. `lm.beta` does a post hoc transformation of non-standardize coefficients to standardized coefficients, so the formula is different. However, the correct pre-regression standardization of your variables produces the same results.

Your error: `(score-mean(score)/sd(score))` should be`(score-mean(score))/sd(score)`. Order of operations matters!

Check it:

```
> (score[1]-mean(score))/sd(score)
[1] 1.923202 #Clearly standardized
> (score[1]-mean(score)/sd(score))
[1] 656.4671 #Clearly NOT standardized!
```

So:

```
stdscore<-(score-mean(score))/sd(score)
stdincome<-(income-mean(income))/sd(income)
lm1e<-lm(stdscore~stdincome)

lm.beta(lm1)
 income 
0.7124308 

lm1e$coef[2]
stdincome 
0.7124308 

round(lm.beta(lm1),5) == round(lm1e$coef[2],5)
income 
  TRUE
```